# Proof of cyclomatic complexity formula

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have come across this formula

> The complexity M is then defined as :
>
> M = E − N + 2P,
>
> where
>
> E = the number of edges of the graph.
>
> N = the number of nodes of the graph.
>
> P = the number of connected components.

from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

Can you explain to me how this formula is derived ?

I would like both a theoretical proof and an intuitive one if possible.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it might attract better answers at the mathematics site.

Comment: @Luuklag so i should post it there?

Comment: Yes, but make sure to read their guidelines before posting.

Comment: Also see the info of the [tag:discrete-mathematics] https://stackoverflow.com/tags/discrete-mathematics/info